# How do I stop Dreamweaver from putting dependent files?

Tags: dreamweaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dreamweaver Keeps Getting Dependent Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026072/dreamweaver-keeps-getting-dependent-files)

I'm using Dreamweaver (CS5) to manage files on a webserver. I have it set so that when I save a file (locally or not) it uploads to the server.

The problem is that when I save/upload a file that links to other files (images, js, css, etc) those files have to upload (or at least check to make sure they are the same) as well.

This becomes an big issue when I'm editing a CSS file with 2000 lines of code and links to hundreds of images.

Is there a way to prevent dreamweaver from uploading everything?

Is there a better Rich text-editor/FTP client for windows

Answer (score 46):

Go to: >Edit on the main toolbar, >Preferences, >Site

[image: Site]

Then Select "Prompt on put/check in"

Once you save / put you will get this dialog box:

[image]

Select "No" for the "Put dependent files" 
Select "Don't show me this message again"

Comment: How did you get that dependent files popup?

Comment: After you make the change on the site, then save a file, the "put dependent file" dialog should appear

Comment: Unfortunately there is a bug with this FYI. Even if you check the box in preferences as well and tell it to not bug you about it anymore after restarting DW it will keep popping up. So annoying.

Comment: This also works in Dreamweaver CC. +1

Comment: Nice! I loved DW but moved on to more mature IDEs!

Answer (score 5):

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Site

Then uncheck "Prompt on put/check in".

Comment: that just prompts you. It doesn't actually prevent putting depentant files.

Answer (score -4):

nope.  there is no friggin' way.  Dreamweaver is an intransigent bastard when it comes to that.  you can see my comments on the Adobe Help forums...

YOU CANNOT STOP DREAMWEAVER FROM TRYING TO UPLOAD DEPENDENT FILES.

the best thing i've managed is to *indicate* the files i don't want by setting the 'cloak' flag.  'cloak' doesn't actually work (seriously, Adobe?  WTH?), but it does pop up a dialog that let's you say 'No to ALL'.  quite frankly, it's a bloody joke, that...

as for a better RichText editor, do you mean a color-coding IDE?  in addition to being a great editor period, Notepad++ also has an FTP plugin that is really great.  if you want a standalone FTP client, can't do better than (Filezilla)[http://filezilla-project.org/]. and if you're balls-of-steel brave, willing to smash your way through the godawful uptake period, (Aptana Studio 3)[http://aptana.com/] is exquisite.  just don't expect a lot of useful tutorials on getting this stonkblonker configured without a lot a head smashing, loud cursing and google-till-you-puke.  once you do, however, it's pretty rockin'.  but my fave is still Dreamweaver because of the wicked smart ability to load all the referenced files in the header.  remember, it was designed for VISUAL development, so that's where it's focused. but it's the best damn IDE i know of for Wordpress, MooTools and Smarty.

anyway.  there you go.  *whew*

WR!