# Dreamweaver Keeps Getting Dependent Files

Tags: file, adobe, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I installed Dreamweaver and when I was downloading the dependent files from my website, it asked me if I always wanted to do this. I said yes, and now, a couple weeks later, I don't want that anymore because it takes 30 seconds to download one little PHP file due to the dependent files.

I cannot find anywhere in the settings where I would be able to disable this again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences -> Site category, check the prompt on GET/PUT checkboxes. The next time you GET/PUT file a dialog will display asking you how you want to handle dependent files. There's a do not show again checkbox on that dialog check/uncheck as appropriate for your usage, and then click OK.

Comment: Works the same on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not showing the dialog box that allows you to select whether dependant files will be sent, then you need to click the Put button with your actual mouse while holding down Alt. Then you'll be able to change your previous choice.

Comment: Changing in preferences didn't work for me - this did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Dreamwveaver CS6**

Its late but i'll add.

`Edit > Preference > General => Enable Related Files (Uncheck this option)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press ALT key and drag the file you want to transfer. This will force DW to ask if you want to include dependent files. Check it as you prefer in the dialog box. This operation can be done on the Upload or Download.